# Building a custom PayPal return URL before POST

Tags: php, forms, button, paypal

I have a **PayPal Button form** and I need to generate the **return URL** from form data. I am looking for suggestions on good way to accomplish this with the example below:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<?php 
$Fname = $_POST["first_name"];
$Lname = $_POST["last_name"];
?>
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="">    
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="">
<?php
$fullname = $Fname . " " . $Lname;
$urlstring = "http://somedomain.com/someapp.php?fullname=" . $fullname;
?>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" NAME="address_override" VALUE="1">
<input type="hidden" NAME="return" VALUE="<?php echo $urlstring; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="aaabbbcccdddeee">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"        border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"   height="1"></p>
</form>
```

Anyone?

Comment: whats problem are you facing here??

Answer (score 0):

You need to first enable the 'Auto Return' option in you paypal account.

Then just add return to you're form with the wanted url

```
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.yoursite.com/checkout_complete.php">
```

If you want to have a more reliable information about the transaction you should also use the notify url parameter wich will send

```
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.yoursite.com/ipn.php">
```

More information here : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside
And here : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside

Comment: I have it enabled and everything works OK except after transaction completion it returns to the url set in $urlstring WITHOUT the var $fullname. The problem is the var is not assigned from the forms input until POST and this is too late. I need to build the $urlstring var prior to POST. Any ideas anyone?